# How pass parameters to an AdonisJs Relationship?

Tags: adonis.js

it is possible?

**Example:**

```
point (id = null) {
  return this.hasOne('App/Models/Account/Account', 'point_code', 'code').where('region_id', id)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah it's totally possible, only consider following:

1. The `id` value you're trying to pass is related to the `Account` model
2. If you pass an `empty` id then probably you will get an empty array of results

If you make this:

```
point (id = null) {
  return this.hasOne('App/Models/Account/Account', 'point_code', 'code').where('region_id', id)
}
```

this will get an `empty` result if you have your `id` as PK

And if you make this

```
point (id = 1) {
  return this.hasOne('App/Models/Account/Account', 'point_code', 'code').where('region_id', id)
}
```

you will receive a single value